# How to call a public function from a sub

Tags: excel, vba

I need to call a public function that contains `vlookup`

```
Sub test()

Dim result As String
result = Call tes ("snowwhite") // does not compile , i also tried with/out colon
//now i hit <ENTER> and get a message Compile Error Expected : Expression 

End Sub


Public Function tes(nm As String) As String


Dim ws2 As Worksheet

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test2")

    result = Aplication.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(nm, ws2.Range("B:B"), 2, False)

End Function
```

How can i improve my code . i get stuck when i try to call the public function

Comment: use this one instead: `result= tes ("snowwhite")` and remove line `With ws2` in your function

Comment: i tried this . this was my first version and since it did not compile i switched to :=

Comment: this line: `VLookup(nm, ws2.Range("B:B"), 2, False)`, range `"B:B"` contains only one column, but you tries to get second: `, 2,` - change to 1

Comment: also change `Aplication.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` to `Application.VLookup` and `result = ...` to `tes= ...`

Comment: Thank you. However , i the `result = ` line still highlited in red by excel

Comment: see my previous comment (I've updated it)

Comment: What do I do with `result = Call tes ("snowwhite")`

Comment: use just `result= tes ("snowwhite")`

Comment: Thank you . i though i needed to use `Call` as with sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow up from comments to Q, correct code would be:

```
Sub test()
    Dim result As Variant
    result = tes("snowwhite")
    'if vlookup doesn't return error (value found)
    If Not IsError(result) Then
        'do sth
    End If
End Sub


Public Function tes(nm As String)
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test2")
    tes = Application.VLookup(nm, ws2.Range("B:B"), 1, False)
End Function
```